# Continue GIF Animation when jQuery.html() is rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading, animation, asynchronous

I have a call on:

```
$(this).ajaxButtonLoading("button", null);
```

What does appear that an animated GIF appears in place of the button. Ate there alright.

I click a button displays an animated gif in place, and a call is made in Ajax to load a content when the jQuery.ajax function is called "success"

I get the contents of this form:

```
success:function(data) {
  $(".panel").html(data);
}
```

It turns out that, while rendering the contents of this "data", my animated GIF is "locked" until all content is rendered. Is there any way to not lock the contents of the site, while another content is rendered.

The content passed by variable "data" is a little mean big, it makes reloading another page, there are other links javascripts being recharged.

Comment: Is your ajax running synchronously or Asynchronously?

Comment: Can you use templates instead of inserting a large chunk of HTML? In most browsers this will cause it to lock... It is better practice to use javascript templates and return JSON from the server side call.